# Text overflows on screen for Ubuntu Server 20.04 (installed on Raspberry Pi) on television display

Tags: server, raspberrypi

I have a newly installed version of Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4B, but the text is overflowing off the edges of the screen.

I see this:

```
u@ubuntu:~$
```

when I expect to see:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

How can I get the screen content to fit in my display without overflowing?

Comment: Have you set 1:1 pixel mapping on the TV for the selected source? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1:1_pixel_mapping

Comment: Thank you @FedonKadifeli, on my Samsung TV I set the Picture Options / Size to Screen Fit and the tty is now fitting my screen. I didn't have to make any other changes in Ubuntu. I didn't think about changing settings on my TV!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a TV as a monitor, the first thing you should do *on the TV* should be setting
[**1:1 pixel mapping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1:1_pixel_mapping)
for the selected source.